# Simpler way to write if statement: passing 1 or 2 parameters in method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, parameter-passing

I wondered if there was a shorter/ simpler way to write the code below.

```
if statement
  result = model.find_by(key => row[key.to_s])
else
  result = model.find_by(key => row[key.to_s], secondkey => row[secondkey.to_s])
end
```

I was thinking of something like this:

```
args = {key => row[key.to_s]}
result = model.find_by(args)
```

But I don't know how to do it that way.

### Edit:

Thanks for your answers!
And how should I write this if situation is below?
I like to put the `args = {key => row[key.to_s]}` before the loop, i try to avoid checking the statement each time.

```
statement = true

rows.each do |row|

  if statement
    result = model.find_by(key => row[key.to_s])
  else
    result = model.find_by(key => row[key.to_s], secondkey => row[secondkey.to_s])
  end

  # more code
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest something like this

```
args = { key: row[key.to_s] }
args.merge!({ secondkey: row[secondkey.to_s] }) if statement
result = model.find_by(args)
```

To avoid queries every loop you maybe can do something like:

```
statement = true
first_condition = row.map { |h| h[: key] }
second_condition = row.map { |h| h[:secondkey] }
result1 = model.where(key: first_condition)
result2 = model.where(key: first_condition, secondkey: second_condition)
```

This will give you two relations to work with, without additional queries to select.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Do you also have a answer for the second question? See edit of post.

Comment: I've added what i should do if i have to iterate many records with some `statement`. So I think its better to take two selections, and thand do one `if statement` to apply different logic for two butches if its needed